# Naming Ruby methods

Tags: ruby, oop

Given a class:

```
class Shell
  attr_reader :spiral
  def initialize spiral
    @spiral = spiral
  end

  def ?????
    # do stuff...
  end
end

some_shell = Shell.new([[1,2],[4,3])
some_shell.spiral #=> [[1,2],
                  #    [4,3]]
some_shell.?????  #=> [1,2,3,4]
```

Does it make more sense to name `?????`:

```
unwrap_spiral
```

or

```
unwrapped_spiral
```

It seems like `unwrap_spiral` is saying to `some_shell`, "I want you to unwrap that spiral" and `unwrapped_spiral` is saying to `some_shell`, "I want you to give me an unwrapped spiral".

I read in [POODR](http://www.poodr.com/):

> The distinction between a message that asks for what the sender wants and a message that tells the receiver how to behave may seem subtle but the consequences are significant.

Which seems like it would be better to choose `unwrapped_spiral`.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naming things is one of the classical two (out of three) hard things to do. 
Jokes aside, I am guided as follows:

1. Am I inquiring about a property of the object? Then my method name is a noun that represents that property.
2. Am I converting the object to another form? Then my method name is "to_target". In your case it could be to_unwrapped.
3. Am I asking the object to carry on some processing internally? Then my method name is a verb. For example, "climb" to climb the spiral.
4. For completeness; Am I building an object from another? Then my factory method is usually called from "from_source". Hypothetically in your case, "from_unwrapped."

Answer (score 2):

Ruby seems to place unusual emphasis on the intent of names and the implications of them. For example, `unwrap_spiral` implies that it might do the operation in-place unless there was a compantion method like `unwrap_spiral!` that made it clear it didn't.

`unwrapped_spiral` may be a shade too verbose. It's not clear why `spiral` factors into this so much when `unwrapped` might suffice.

Another thing to consider is organizing methods that operate on `spiral` under the same alphabetic ordering: `spiral_unwrap` or `spiral_unwrapped`.

Answer (score 2):

I actually think there is already a method called `flatten` that seems to result in the same result.

http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/flatten

If you have a more advanced custom method, I would go with `unspiral`

Comment: The method isn't `flatten`, even though it looks like it at first.

Comment: +1 for unspiral, please check see my comment on [Chris Heald's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41655195/2909897) answer about the `#flatten` confusion

Answer (score 1):

My inclination would be that rather than `Shell` having an `Array` spiral, to have a `Spiral` class (which may just be a subclass of `Array`) which has an `unwrap` method (which in this case would just alias to `Array#flatten`).

```
class Spiral < Array
  def unwrap
    flatten
  end
end

class Shell
  attr_reader :spiral
  def initialize(spiral)
    # Or if your convention would allow, accept `spiral` as an Array
    # and assign @spiral = Spiral.new(spiral)
    @spiral = spiral
  end
end

> shell = Shell.new Spiral.new([[1,2],[4,3]])
 => #<Shell:0x000000018286f0 @spiral=[[1, 2], [4, 3]]>
> shell.spiral
 => [[1, 2], [4, 3]]
> shell.spiral.unwrap
 => [1, 2, 4, 3]
```

The reason this makes sense because the concept you want to operate on in this case is the `Spiral`, which belongs to the `Shell`, rather than the shell itself. This opens you up to having additional methods which operate on the spiral itself. As the implementation of Spiral gets more complex, Shell wouldn't have to necessarily get any more complex - it could simply expose and operate on the Spiral's public interface.

Comment: That'd be my philosophy as well. Note that `unwrap` isn't just `flatten`, though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. To clarify `some_shell.?????` is intentionally "unwrapping" and not "flattening". That is I want: `[1, 2, 3, 4]` not `[1, 2, 4, 3]`

Comment: Ah. Then I'd just make `#unwrap` -> `flatten.sort` :)

Answer (score 1):

## Shell < Spiral

In your example, `Shell` only lives for `@spiral`, so you might :

- define `Spiral` class
- let `Shell` inherit from `Spiral`
- define `Spiral#unwrap` (`Array#flatten` isn't called `flattened`)
- use `Shell(Spiral)#unwrap`

## Shell#spiral

If `Shell` is more than just its `@spiral`, you could :

- define `Spiral` class anyway
- define `Spiral#unwrap`
- use `Shell#spiral#unwrap` : `shell.spiral.unwrap`